# Django: disappearing filter_horizontal after overriding a form field

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a many2many field in model:

`models.py`

```
pages = models.ManyToManyField(Page, verbose_name='Pages', blank=True)
```

And for admin interface **filter_horizontal** works just fine:

`admin.py`

```
filter_horizontal = ['pages',]
```

But when i overriding this field, using **forms.Modelform** (for changing queryset) - in interface it begins to show like a simple `<select>` field:

`forms.py`

```
class BannerAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    pages = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Page.objects.filter(publisher_is_draft=0), label='Pages')

    class Meta:
        model = Banners
```

`admin.py`

```
class BannersAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = BannerAdminForm
    filter_horizontal = ['pages',]
```

Is there any solution for this problem? I looked for some special widgets for **ModelMultipleChoiceField**, but don't find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't address the actual issue but is an alternative approach to setting the queryset:

```
class BannerAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
         super(BannerAdminForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
         self.fields['pages'].queryset = Page.objects.filter(publisher_is_draft=0)

    class Meta:
        model = Banners
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this snippet](https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2466/), you can specify the widget of the field as `FilteredSelectMultiple`

Comment: Hm... to many code to write... but i think this changes may work too